# Change Java-classes of Android-JDK via reflection

Tags: android, reflection, dalvik, intercept

I wonder if something like this is possible:

1. Application AA uses Androids class [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to play some songs to
   STREAM_MUSIC
2. Application BB changes/replaces some methods in Androids class MediaPlayer via
   standard Java-reflection methods
3. The MediaPlayer-instance of application AA
   uses the by application BB replaced methods

I'm sure in a simple java-application this could work (once, I replaced some methods in an external library via reflection).

But I'm not sure if that would work in Android. I think the apps are separated from each other and can just communicate via notifications, because this would be a very large security leak.

My intention is to find a way to grab audio from other apps and I'm searching & trying since almost 1 year now.

Kind regards & thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder if something like this is possible

Fortunately, no. While processes share the initial class definitions, any app that somehow modifies those definitions will transparently work on a new private copy (Linux copy-on-write).

> My intention is to find a way to grab audio from other apps

Fortunately, that is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I don't understand the downvotes (by whomsoever) because I think it's an appropriate question.

Comment: @MartinM.: I didn't downvote you, but it might be their interpretation of your intentions, trying to steer you away from doing things (e.g., wiretaps) that have ethical considerations and may be illegal in your jurisdiction.

Comment: sure, no problem. There are enough bad people out there :) Ps. I just would like to stream to my wireless speakers but use my default player to do this, like iPhone can.

Comment: @MartinM.: Yeah, that would require OS-level changes, unless the speakers are Bluetooth, in which case they probably can just pair with the Android device and work.